# Descarga archivo csv en JSP

Tags: java, jsp, csv

En un evento onclick, estoy intentando que se descargue un archivo csv con FileWriter, pero descarga en una ruta específica que yo proporciono

¿Cómo debería hacer para que se descargue automáticamente y se muestre en el navegador el archivo descargado?

El código es el siguiente:

```
private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = " ,";

private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";

private static final String FILE_HEADER = "Banca,Par de Divisa,Segmento,"+
   "Segmento-Compra,Segmento-Venta,Zona,Zona-Compra,Zona-Venta,Canal,"+
   "Canal-Compra,Canal-Venta,Monto,"+
   "Monto-Compra,Monto-Venta,Total Compra,Total Venta";

String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/registros.csv";


        FileWriter fileWriter = null;

        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

            fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());

            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

            for (InfoMatrixSpreads info : listmatrix) {

                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getBanking()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getCurrencyPar()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getSegment()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getSegmentBuySpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getSegmentSaleSpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getZone()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getZoneBuySpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getZoneSaleSpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getChannel()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getChannelBuySpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getChannelSaleSpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getAmount()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getAmountBuySpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getAmountSaleSpread()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getTotalBuy()));
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(info.getTotalSale()));
                fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
            }

            System.out.println("CSV file was created successfully !!!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta para ver tu codigo

Comment: ya lo hice, gracias

Comment: Ese código no compila: no hay ningún método definido

Comment: La pregunta seria si lo que estas haciendo lo haces en un ambiente web o en que tipo de programa?

Comment: Hola @Paula. Es importante que le des contexto a las preguntas... Edité agregando la etiqueta [tag:jsp] (que sino nadie puede adivinar que es en entorno web), y aclaré que el código se ejecuta en un onclick... Por favor revisá mi edición para verificarla (y/o tener en cuenta estos detalles en otras preguntas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te falta es obtener los `bytes` de tu `String` el que llenas cuando recorres la lista cuando tengas los `bytes` lo mandas a  escribirlo, eso lo hace en la variable que se llama `resultado` así podrias descargar el archivo te dejo un ejemplo es parecido al tuyo solo que sin la lista que recorres.

```
File file = new 
File("C:\\temp\\downloadfilename.csv");
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
 ServletOutputStream out = 
 response.getOutputStream();

 byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
 //copy binary contect to output stream
 while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
 {
out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
 }
 fileIn.close();
 out.flush();
  out.close();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, lo probé y el código no me genera error, pero no descarga el archivo, sabes que podría ser?

Comment: Podrías mostrarme el botón donde haces la llamada

Comment: en el jsp, lo tengo con una función onclick, será ese el problema??

Comment: Te edite la respuesta con un código como ya generas el cvs en una ruta especifica, ahí te puse código para descargarlo